# Wordpress custom query on post title and category

Tags: wordpress

I want to filter lists of posts whcih contains a specific word in post title and belong to one or more categories. how can i achieve this ?

Ex: Get posts with the word "PHP" in post title and belongs to category "PHP" and "Code"

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom loops for this purpose. 
Read this tutorial: http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-custom-the-posts-i-commented-on-loop/